# How to parametrize on iterator direction?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, iterator, foreach

Basically I'm doing the following:

```
std::set<int> indices;
// ..fill indices

if (flag)
{
   // we need to process in ascending order
   BOOST_FOREACH (int i, indices) 
   {
      process(i);
   }
}
else
{
   // we need to process in descending order
   BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH (int i, indices) 
   {
      process(i);
   }
}
```

I wonder if there's a way to write the same thing in C++03 with just one call to process(i), somehow parametrizing on the processing order? Like this (which obviously doesn't work even in C++0x because begin() and rbegin() return different types):

```
   auto iter = flag ? indices.begin() : indices.rbegin();
   auto end =  flag ? indices.end() : indices.rend();

   BOOST_FOREACH (int i, std::make_pair(iter, end)) 
   {
      process(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want can be implemented with [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/variant.html).

The idea is to define a new type of iterator which stores a variant (think of it like a C union on steroids) containing either a forward or reverse iterator:

```
template<class InputRange>
struct any_dir_iterator
: std::iterator_traits<typename boost::range_iterator<InputRange>::type> {

    typedef typename boost::range_iterator<InputRange>::type forward_iterator;
    typedef typename 
        boost::range_reverse_iterator<InputRange>::type reverse_iterator;

    typedef boost::variant<forward_iterator, reverse_iterator> iterator_type;

    iterator_type current_it, end_it;

    any_dir_iterator(InputRange & input_range, 
                     bool fwd = true, 
                     bool end = false) 
    {
        end_it = fwd ? iterator_type(boost::end(input_range)) 
                     : iterator_type(boost::rend(input_range));

        if(end)
            current_it = end_it;
        else
            current_it = fwd ? iterator_type(boost::begin(input_range)) 
                             : iterator_type(boost::rbegin(input_range));
    }

    reference operator*() const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(dereference_visitor<any_dir_iterator>(), 
                                    current_it);
    }

    any_dir_iterator & operator++() {
        boost::apply_visitor(increment_visitor<any_dir_iterator>(), 
                             current_it);
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(any_dir_iterator const & rhs) {
        return boost::apply_visitor(equals_visitor<any_dir_iterator>(), 
                                    current_it, rhs.current_it);
    }    
};
```

This is similar to [Adobe's any iterator](http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1any__iterator.html) but much less general, which means that it will have virtually no performance overhead when compared to a plain iterator.

As you can see in the code above, all the logic is delegated to static visitors which we  define as follows:

```
template<class AnyDirIterator>
struct dereference_visitor 
: boost::static_visitor<typename AnyDirIterator::iterator_type> {

    typedef typename AnyDirIterator::reference result_type;

    template<class FwdOrRevIterator>
    result_type operator()(FwdOrRevIterator const & it) const { 
        return *it; 
    }
};

template<class AnyDirIterator>
struct increment_visitor 
: boost::static_visitor<typename AnyDirIterator::iterator_type> {

    typedef void result_type;

    template<class FwdOrRevIterator>
    result_type operator()(FwdOrRevIterator & it) const {
        ++it;
    }
};

template<class AnyDirIterator>
struct equals_visitor 
: boost::static_visitor<typename AnyDirIterator::iterator_type>
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    template <typename FwdOrRevIterator>
    bool operator()(FwdOrRevIterator const & lhs, 
                    FwdOrRevIterator const & rhs) const {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()( const T &, const U & ) const {
        return false; // comparing fwd to rev or vice-versa
    }
};
```

That was the tricky part. But we still have to make this more convenient to use, for which we define a helper function that relies on the functionality provided by the [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/index.html) library:

```
template<class InputRange>
boost::iterator_range<any_dir_iterator<InputRange> > 
make_any_dir_range(InputRange & range, bool forward=true) {
    typedef any_dir_iterator<InputRange> iterator;
    return boost::make_iterator_range(iterator(range, forward),
                                      iterator(range, forward, true));
}
```

And that is all. Now you can write:

```
int main() {

    int items[] = { 1, 2 };
    typedef std::vector<int> container_type;
    container_type container(items, items + sizeof(items)/sizeof(items[0]));

    BOOST_FOREACH(int i, make_any_dir_range(container, true))
        std::cout << i << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
    BOOST_FOREACH(int i, make_any_dir_range(container, false))
        std::cout << i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```
1 2
2 1
```

This works with const containers as well, although I haven't shown that possibility in the `main` function.

Another nice thing which results from using Boost.Range is that this works with arrays out of the box. So you can do this:

```
int items[] = { 1, 2 };

BOOST_FOREACH(int i, make_any_dir_range(items, true)) // Prints "1 2"
    std::cout << i << " ";
```

Too keep this answer short I've left a few things unimplemented (but they're all boilerplate, not requiring new visitors):

- The postfix increment operator
- The != operator
- The -> operator

Here's [all the code in Codepad](http://codepad.org/vc8ZxL7a). Due to the "treat warnings as errors" policy Codepad won't swallow it but both VS2008 and GCC 4.4 compile it OK in my local machine.

**UPDATE**

I've made some tests and apparently `boost::variant` does introduce some runtime overhead: a `BOOST_FOREACH`-based loop like the one in the `main` function runs about 4 times slower (when compiled in release mode) than the equivalent version using a plain iterator. It would be interesting to check whether this is best or worst than the overhead introduced by Adobe's `any_iterator`.

Comment: Wow, this is way more than I expected ;) I wonder if the solution with a good 'ol union would be possible. But I already think that having an extra if is better than to introduce this complicated code. It could be worth it if I was doing this kind of thing constantly, but it's just in a couple of places. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Alex - I don't think unions can be used here, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943267/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-unions-in-c/943611#943611

Answer (score 1):

Well the obvious one is to make a class which handles the logic of this situation, either through storing a flag, or using polymorphism. However, it would at best be "hiding" the `if` statement.

Comment: Could you please sketch the logic of handling this situation without using macros in the rough? The way I see it, inside of this class there still will be two (indirect) calls to process in two different loops.

Comment: You could use templates for the implementation (one loop, two scenarios). I don't see how you can at *runtime* determine the iterator types to use - even with macros -, without having coded the logic for both iterators.