# Is there any way to access QByteArray member which is member of a union

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, unions, qbytearray

I'm using **union** that have 2 members. One's type is **QByteArray**, other's **double**. I want to access QByteArray members after *changing value* of the double array.

I've tried this using with char * (size = 8) and double union members. There was no problem.

```
 union smt{
        QByteArray qbyte;             
        double *data;
        ~smt(){}    // needs to know which member is active, only possible in union-like class
    };

     smt x={"sometng"};
     double *result =...;  
     memcpy(x.data,result,sizeof (double)); // copy result to x.data
```

In this code I want to *access* the values of the QByteArray after changing the data array. Basically I want to get the string values *corresponding* the double values. 
If they are sharing the *same memory space*, theoretically it's possible, right?

However, after changing the data array, I got runtime error, that says the QByteArray **"not accessible"**

Am I missing something or doing smtg wrong? Please help me

Thank you, in advance

Comment: 1. QByteArray is not trivial, POD type, so what you want is impossible. 2. Reading a value of an union member that was not used for writing a value is undefined behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943267/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-unions-in-c

Comment: This is all undefined behaviour, I would strungly recommend not using this technique. If you describe the problem you are trying to solve then someone may be able to offer a suggestion

Comment: You can use QVariant instead of union